# Can't Run H2o in R due to Java

Tags: java, r, h2o

I'm running Windows 10 64 bit. 
I went to the command prompt and typed java -version to check the version.

The result told me java version "1.8.0_251" and 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode)

However, when I'm trying to run H2o in R, error occurs:

```
You have a 32-bit version of Java. H2O works best with 64-bit Java. 
Please download the latest Java SE JDK from the following URL: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html
```

I have tried downloading the recent Java SE 14 64 bit version and restarted R session, but the same error occurs. I have looked at my control panel and checked that my Java is 64 bit too.

So now I am completely lost in dealing with this Java problem. Anybody got some clue?

Comment: you still have a 32-bit version installed somewhere.  go to control panel and uninstall it.  or you can also try to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable to the correct 64-bit path.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have 32-bit version of Java installed as well as your new 64-bit version.

H2O may find Java differently than what your terminal finds from `Java -version`. The order H2O finds Java is:

1. Searches in `PATH`
2. If not found, then checks `JAVA_HOME`

You have a few options to resolve your issue:

- Uninstall your old 32-bit version of Java as @TomKraljevic mentioned
- Add the new 64-bit Java to the beginning of your Windows `PATH` system variable [under Windows settings](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)
- Add the new 64-bit Java to the beginning of `PATH` in your R environment. For example:

```
old_path <- Sys.getenv("PATH")
ys.setenv(PATH = paste("path/to/new_java", old_path, sep = ":"))
```